# Attention The file was not uploaded

Tags: magento-2.1, downloadable, file-upload

I am trying to create a downloadable product in Magento 2.1.7 but when I try to upload the downloadable file, I am getting this error:

> Attention The file was not uploaded.

I tried changing the version but get the same result. Even when I try the direct URL to download the file, it shows error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error can be caused by server permissions / configurations.
It could simply be a permission issue so please ensure your web server user has full rights as per it's recommended in devdocs http://bit.ly/2v325mQ.

If that doesn't resolve the issue then you may want to look at the file size and see it's not larger than the allowed file size on your server.

Comment: How to change the file size??

Comment: Increase the values of upload_max_filesize in your php.ini file and if necessary change post_max_size too.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several Issue for this Error.

1. There Could be wrong ownership assigned to the required pub/media directory in case if it is media otherwise var/ folder.
2. We need to provide Permission to read and write to the Magento user as well as the Apache Usergroup.
3. The another issue could be the PHP configurations of the file_uploads should be enabled and upload_max_filesize, post_max_size configurations should be higher then the size of actual file you are trying to upload.

You can also increase the max_execution_time in case your file is large and takign longer time to execute on the server.

If this answer help you in any way you can upvote, I shall be thankful.